# Can't execute 'mysql' on WP CLI docker container

Tags: docker-compose, wp-cli

I'm trying to run [this](https://github.com/michaelperrin/automated-wordpress-demo) project to automate my Wordpress installations. I have little knowledge about Docker, so I'm with difficulties to fix this error:

[image]